# Select different dates from mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a database structure like this

```
ID | title | startTime | endTime
```

And what I need is to get 3 records from the database where the first recorder is following this structure `DAY(NOW())-1` the second record has to be like `DAY(NOW())` or the first upcoming record and the third has to be like `DAY(NOW())+1` 
What I was able to do is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime) as start FROM tl_calendar_events  
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime)) = MONTH(NOW()) 
AND DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime)) >= DAY(NOW()) 
ORDER BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime)) ASC LIMIT 3;
```

But this will return the first 3 upcoming records. The `startTime` and `endTime` are all unix timestamp fields. So the final output of this query would look something like this if I take that the date is: `06-12-2015`:

1. Record #1 (startTime - 10-11-2015)
2. Record #2 (startTime - 06-12-2015)
3. Record #3 (startTime - 12-01-2016)

Also I need some sort of a DISTINCT select so that if it happens I have like 3 records with the on the same day I only select one. I figured I could do this with 3 joins but just ended up creating a lot of mess. I hope you understood my question and can provide some help.

**SAMPLE DATA:**

- Event #1 (04-11-2015)
- Event #2 (06-12-2015)
- Event #3 (10-12-2015)
- Event #4 (12-03-2016)
- Event #5 (17-04-2016)

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

- EVENT #2 (as it is the first one before the current date)
- EVENT #3 (as it is the current date or the first closest match)
- EVENT #4 (as it is the first one to come after event #3)

I hope this will help explain my situation much better.

Comment: You probably need GROUP BY

Comment: This question isn't very clear as it stands, can you add some more info like sample data and expected output from that sample data?

Comment: @TomV I have updated the description with the sample data and sample output of what my result should look like. As this is a table in the db that holds calendar events

Comment: If events 3 and 4 were the same date (but different time) would you still want events 2, 3 and 4 in the result? Or it should be then 2, 3 and 5 (with different date than 3)?

Comment: @ypercube I only want one event per day so if there are more events with the same day just select one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use yyyy-mm-dd to avoid confusion (mm-dd-yyyy vs dd-mm-yyyy) and be consistent with MySQL.

Does this give you the first item you want?

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE ts < CURRENT_DATE()
    ORDER BY ts DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

If so, does this give you the other two:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE ts > $foo
    ORDER BY ts
    LIMIT 2;
```

given that $foo is the timestamp you got from the first query.

I assume your `ts` is of datatype `TIMESTAMP`, not `INT`.  `DATETIME` would also do.

If you need to display dd-mm-yyyy, use `DATE_FORMAT` in the `SELECT`, but not for internal calculations.